# Sending USDC dev token not working until recepient wallet has >0 value of said token

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, solana-wallet-adapter, spl-token-program, spl-associated-token-account

I am trying to send usdc dev token using code to a wallet address but it kept on showing "Unable to simulate. Make sure you trust this website since approving can lead to loss of funds."

And even if I approve, tx would get rejected.

After hours of debugging, I tried first sending a little of the usdc token to that wallet address and then tried to resend again using my code and it worked fine.

So I was wondering, must the wallet have a bit of that token before being able to send to it using code? If yes, is there a way to do it successfully using code? Because that's my main goal

code below:

```
import {
  createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction,
  createTransferInstruction,
  getAssociatedTokenAddress,
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
} from "@solana/spl-token";
import { useConnection, useWallet } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import { PublicKey, Transaction } from "@solana/web3.js";

//to convert the wallet address to usdc dev
async function convertToUsdcDev(address) {
  const mint = new PublicKey("Gh9ZwEmdLJ8DscKNTkTqPbNwLNNBjuSzaG9Vp2KGtKJr");
  const owner = new PublicKey(address);

  const tokenAddress = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(mint, owner);
  console.log(console.log("tokenAddress.toBase58()", tokenAddress.toBase58()));
  return tokenAddress.toBase58();
}
```

```
function usePayUSDC() {
  const { connection } = useConnection();
  const { publicKey, sendTransaction } = useWallet();

  // Token
  const valueTokenAddress = "Gh9ZwEmdLJ8DscKNTkTqPbNwLNNBjuSzaG9Vp2KGtKJr";
  const mint = new PublicKey(valueTokenAddress);

  const NUM_DROPS_PER_TX = 4;
  const TX_INTERVAL = 1000;

  // populate this with the amount to be sent, from req.body.amount
  const valueAmount = 10;

  async function generateTransactions(batchSize, dropList) {
    let result = [];

    const payerPublicKey = publicKey;

    const payerTokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
      mint,
      payerPublicKey
    );

    const payerAccountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(payerTokenAccount);

    // Token
    let txInstructions = dropList.map((drop) => {
      const takerTokenAccount = new PublicKey(drop.walletAddress);

      if (!payerAccountInfo || !payerAccountInfo.data) {
        createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
          payerPublicKey,
          payerTokenAccount,
          payerPublicKey,
          mint // mint
        );
      }
      return createTransferInstruction(
        payerTokenAccount,
        takerTokenAccount,
        payerPublicKey,
        Number(drop.amount) * 10 ** 6,
        [],
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID // programId
      );
    });
   //some more code here
    return result;
  }

//execute tx function here ----

  async function transfer(data) {
    const { amount, wallet } = data;
    const usdcWallet = await convertToUsdcDev(wallet);

    const dropList = [
      {
        walletAddress: "vjm7kKuECdbR7Ste2c3DPDS6u9Pzccy2vsuXH9BSHs3",
        amount: (amount * 0.08163).toFixed(6),
      },
      {
        walletAddress: usdcWallet,
        amount: (amount * 0.91837).toFixed(6),
      },
    ];

    const transactionList = await generateTransactions(
      NUM_DROPS_PER_TX,
      dropList
    );

    const txResults = await executeTransactions(transactionList);

    return txResults.value || txResults.status;
  }

  return { transfer };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely getting an error because the recipient's token account for that specific mint hasn't been created.

Below is an example for how to build a transaction and add an instruction to create a token account if it doesn't exist.

Note that:

- the example assumes `sender` has an existing token account with a balance for the `MINT`
- the amount transferred hasn't been adjusted for decimals of the `MINT`
- `await initializeKeypair(connection)` is a helper function that isn't shown, but is just another keypair

Other than that you can use it as a reference

```
async function main() {
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"))

  // Generate a new keypair to represent the sender
  const sender = await initializeKeypair(connection)

  // Generate a new keypair to represent the sender
  const receiver = Keypair.generate()

  // The MINT address of token to transfer
  const MINT = new PublicKey("Gh9ZwEmdLJ8DscKNTkTqPbNwLNNBjuSzaG9Vp2KGtKJr")

  // Get the sender's associated token account address
  const senderTokenAccountAddress = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
    MINT,
    sender.publicKey
  )

  // Get the receiver's associated token account address
  const receiverTokenAccountAddress = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
    MINT,
    receiver.publicKey
  )

  // Create a new transaction
  const transaction = new Transaction()

  // Create an instruction to create the receiver's token account if it does not exist
  const createAccountInstruction = createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
    sender.publicKey,
    receiverTokenAccountAddress,
    receiver.publicKey,
    MINT,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
  )

  // Check if the receiver's token account exists
  let receiverTokenAccount: Account
  try {
    receiverTokenAccount = await getAccount(
      connection,
      receiverTokenAccountAddress,
      "confirmed",
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    )
  } catch (e) {
    // If the account does not exist, add the create account instruction to the transaction
    transaction.add(createAccountInstruction)
  }

  // Create an instruction to transfer amount from the sender's token account to the receiver's token account
  const transferInstruction = await createTransferInstruction(
    senderTokenAccountAddress,
    receiverTokenAccountAddress,
    sender.publicKey,
    1
  )

  // Add the transfer instruction to the transaction
  transaction.add(transferInstruction)

  // Send the transaction signed by the sender
  const transactionSignature = await connection.sendTransaction(transaction, [
    sender,
  ])

  console.log(transactionSignature)
}
```

Comment: where are initializeKeypair & Keypair imported from?

Comment: It's a just a custom helper function that creates a new keypair and airdrops some devnet SOL, its not relevant to creating the transaction. It's from a template here: https://github.com/Unboxed-Software/solana-npx-client-template/blob/with-keypair-env/src/initializeKeypair.ts

Here's the reference example: https://github.com/ZYJLiu/token-transfer/tree/master/src

Comment: nice
solution works perfectly

Comment: Pls upvote my question